# "No encryption" error when using PHP "mail" function

Tags: php, encryption

Building a site that currently doesn't have "https".

Trying to test out a login scheme that sends a validation email.

Tried out PHP's `mail()` function, and it worked, except that the email went into Spam in the receiver's Gmail. (This is my first time playing with `mail()`).

**The Question**: Will using SSL on the site (enabling "https") solve this problem? If not, then what will? (Realize that using something like PHPMailer is better, but `mail()` is much much simpler to implement so would prefer using it instead -- if at all possible.)

Error:
[image: screen capture of "No encryption" message in email inside Gmail Spam Folder]

Script:

```
<?php

    $to="receiver's email address";
    $subject="sub: test mail from mail1.php";
    $body="body: test mail from mail1.php";
    $from = "sender's email address";
    $headers = "From:".$from;
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: `but mail() is much much simpler to implement so would prefer using it instead -- if at all possible.` No, it isn't. Its a lot more work to write all the necessary mail-headers and encode everything correctly yourself than just using phpmailer which does all that for you.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks -- will look into `PHPMailer` (haven't actually tried it yet, just assumed it had to be more complicated to install something than to use a built-in PHP function).

Answer (score 2):

> Will using SSL on my site (enabling "https") solve this problem?

No. Whether or not the recipient server considers your email to be spam has nothing to do with whether or not the website on the server that sent the mail is using HTTPS. The encryption complaint has to do with your local email server, not your web server.

> If not, then what will?

Note that the fact your email is in the spam folder is not necessarily because of the lack of encryption. Implementing encryption on your local email server may help but could be a pain -- you'd have to refer to the docs for whatever email server you're running.

You can likely improve your chances by implementing SPF and DKIM on your side.

PHPMailer will not necessarily fare any better. I would recommend a mail service like MailGun instead. They will take care of the SSL for you, and provide services like bounce detection.

Comment: This. Not using encryption is probably a minor factor compared to everything else your email is lacking or doing wrong. Using PHPMailer will address pretty much everything, with the notable exception that you absolutely cannot use a third party's email address as the 'from' address in this day and age.

Answer (score -1):

Try sending header before the mail() function, for example:

```
$header = "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

.
.
.
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

In case this doesn't fix your problem. Please try using PHPMailer instead.

Download the library from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: There's nothing about encryption in those headers so how would that help them? Also, how would PHPMailer help them?